# Executing a raw query results in null response?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to execute a raw query via Laravel, and get back a multi column result.

I've tried using `DB::select` as advised (also `DB::raw)` but always get back null?

The query should give back something like so:

| habit_id | currentStreak |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 |

in Eloquent:

```
DB::select('WITH streaks AS (
            SELECT
                habit_id,
                DATE(created_at) AS dt,
                DATE(created_at) - INTERVAL DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY habit_id ORDER BY DATE(created_at) ASC) DAY AS grp
            FROM habit_progress_logs
            WHERE habit_id = ' . $this->id . '
        ),
        streaks2 AS (
            SELECT
                habit_id,
                grp,
                COUNT(DISTINCT dt) AS length,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY habit_id ORDER BY grp DESC) AS rn
            FROM streaks
            GROUP BY habit_id, grp
        )
        SELECT habit_id, length AS currentStreak
        FROM streaks2
        WHERE rn = 1;');
```

Query works flawlessly outside of Eloquent

Comment: `rn = 1`? whats this in `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works, using exact same query with `selectResultSets` and querying the inner array(s).

```
DB::selectResultSets('WITH streaks AS (
                SELECT
                    habit_id,
                    DATE(created_at) AS dt,
                    DATE(created_at) - INTERVAL DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY habit_id ORDER BY DATE(created_at) ASC) DAY AS grp
                FROM habit_progress_logs
                WHERE habit_id = ' . $this->id . '
            ),
            streaks2 AS (
                SELECT
                    habit_id,
                    grp,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT dt) AS length,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY habit_id ORDER BY grp DESC) AS rn
                FROM streaks
                GROUP BY habit_id, grp
            )
            SELECT habit_id, length AS currentStreak
            FROM streaks2
            WHERE rn = 1;')[0][0]->currentStreak;
```